# Which anime is this image of a snake girl cuddling a boy from?

Tags: story-identification, anime

I just stumbled upon this image on social media:

[image: Cuddling with snake girl]

Can you please identify this anime or the source of the image? Google Reverse Image Search isn’t helping.

Comment: Both with Google Lens from the right click menu in chromium, and google reverse image search, the phrase "monster musume" is incredibly prominent - at the top of both of the pages of results.  What do you mean it "isn't helping"?  Did you post this just to confess your off-topic fantasy?

Comment: @AdamBarnes I am still getting “Fictional Characters” keywords on reverse image search. Now, it also shows this page. If you are getting direct answers now, that’s possibly because of this page.

Comment: @AdamBarnes I just tried doing a google reverse image. I don't find anything relevant; in fact, it can't even find this question. It looks like I'm among the unlucky ones.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is from the harem series *Monster Musume no Iru Nichijou*, also known as *Everyday Life with Monster Girls*. It depicts the protagonist Kimihito being cuddled by the lamia girl Miia, the first of the titular monster girls to join his harem.

*Monster Musume no Iru Nichijou* is primarily a manga, that began in 2012 and is still ongoing, but there was also a 12-episode anime adaptation that aired in 2015. Both the manga and the anime are NSFW, but stop just short of being full-blown hentai.

Comment: "Hanime" is the accepted term.

Answer (score 5):

According to a newspage from Crunchyroll*, the image is from the anime [Monster Musume](https://myanimelist.net/anime/30307/Monster_Musume_no_Iru_Nichijou) (also known as "Everyday Life with Monster Girls").

* No direct link due to NSFW content, search for "crunchyroll Miia July 18, 2015" in Google

Comment: Also, that site is not entirely safe for work either.

Comment: @Clockwork I removed the problematic link

Comment: You could also include the link with a NSFW warning in parenthesis; I've seen it done before, although I don't know if there's a standard for it.